# Testing the hypothesis that $\sum_i^N p_i^2 =(N-1)/2N$ given $\sum_i^N p_i=1$

Tags: binomial-distribution, multinomial-distribution, ecology, diversity

In ecology there is a simple index for measuring *diversity* known as the Simpson index. In it simplest formula, it takes a series of proportions, representing the relative abundance (number of individuals) of each species.

$$ D =  \frac{1}{\sum_i^N p_i^2}$$

As these relative abundances, they all sum to 1, so $\sum_i^N p_i=1$

I'm curious about the inverse of this index. More specifically if we can test the hypothesis that its value is different from the middle-of-interval value.

In other words, $ D^{-1} = \sum_i^N p_i^2$. It should vary from $1/N$, where all relative abundances are equal, to $1$ where only one species is present. The middle value should be $(1-1/N)/2$. I wonder if given a series of $p_i$ one can calculate the probability of $H_0:D^{-1}=  (1-1/N)/2$.

I think this is somehow related to the binomial (or perhaps multinomial test) but cannot figure out exactly what is the proper test for that.

Comment: This looks like a straightforward application of a chi-squared test will do the trick.  Its applicability depends on the underlying *counts,* as would any reasonable test, because the proportions alone will not suffice for a good test.  The alternative for low expected counts is a permutation or bootstrap test.